# Checkbox retains state after postback

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

how come my model retains the state? why is it like this? 
Isn't it supposed to be refreshed since i am trying to send a brand new instance of the model?

Here is an example:
If i delete anything on the middle, after `postback`, the checkbox will still be checked

[image]

Here are my codes:

Here is my postback code:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<Employee> emp)
    {
        EmployeeContext test = new EmployeeContext();
        if (emp.Count(x => x.selected) == 0)
        {           
            return View(test.Employees);
        }
        else
        {

            foreach (Employee del in emp)
            {
                if (del.selected)
                {
                    Employee dummy = test.Employees.Single(x => x.id == del.id);
                    test.Employees.Remove(dummy);
                    test.SaveChanges(); 
              }
          }

          return View(test.Employees);
      }
 }
```

What should i do to remove that state? i read something about `ModelState.Remove` so my idea is that use a loop to clear each of my checkboxes but i am not sure if that will be good when it comes to performance. What should i do?

Comment: You should not be changing values of your properties and returning the view. The correct approach is to follow the PRG pattern (redirect to your GET method)

Comment: Ooooooo i see. Alright let me try that one.

Comment: "If i delete anything in the middle"... what do you mean by that?

Comment: The list and view will be updated, the checkbox will still be checked on that row.

Comment: @CarloBrew, It would be pointless to return the same view with the checkboxes unchecked - it would just mean the user could check them again to delete something which has already been deleted (redirect to the GET method and regenerate the view which will now no longer contain items that have already been deleted :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing them to `Redirect`:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<Employee> emp)
    {
        EmployeeContext test = new EmployeeContext();
        if (emp.Count(x => x.selected) == 0)
        {
           return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {

            foreach (Employee del in emp)
            {
                if (del.selected)
                {
                    Employee dummy = test.Employees.Single(x => x.id == del.id);
                    test.Employees.Remove(dummy);
                    test.SaveChanges(); 
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
}
```

Full Credits to : Stephen Muecke for the `PRG pattern`.

Comment: I didn't see your answer. Sorry but i didn't know that you can vote even if the question is flagged as `duplicate`.

Comment: Ahhh sorry, my question was kinda messy that time. can i fix it?

Comment: Alright, im sorry if you felt that way. My account is old but i am kinda new on SO etiquettes. I'll keep that in mind for future reference. Thanks for the redirection also earlier(I thought having a question being flagged as duplicate is a bad thing so). I Appreciate your help.

Comment: Having a question flagged as a duplicate is not a bad thing at all.

Answer (score 0):

if you didn't want model state keep it's value in the view, you don't need to pass the model into the view
just change this

> return View(test.Employees);

into

> return View();